# Domain Verification for Microsoft Account App in Azure AD for Azure B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

not sure if this belongs here or in Doc's Q&A, techcommunity, but I'm posting in all.

Do I need to have a Microsoft partner account so that the B2C Login app I created for Microsoft accounts says verified or is that just for the blue tick?

Per [Create a Microsoft account application Step 2 from Set up sign-up and sign-in with a Microsoft account using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-user-flow#create-a-microsoft-account-application) You need to make an application in your Azure AD Tenant (not the B2C Tenant). I've done this and the tenant has a verified domain, but it still says 'unverified' when signing in with a Microsoft account. Publisher domain is set to the verified domain of the AAD Tenant.

I know that [Features not applicable in Azure AD B2C tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/app-registrations-training-guide#features-not-applicable-in-azure-ad-b2c-tenants) says publisher domain verification isn't available but:

1. I take that as referring to the apps that B2C will be used to sign you into, not the app you need to create to allow Microsoft accounts to work with B2C
2. The app to make Microsoft accounts work isn't in the B2C Tenant
3. The domain is already verified

How do I get this app for B2C (that isn't in a B2C Tenant) domain verified?

Comment: Maybe try the Super User SE as well?

Comment: Can you add more details or a screenshot about "it still says 'unverified' when signing in with a Microsoft account"?

Comment: There are three types of AAD App Verification:
1. Unverified - says unverified
2. Domain verification - says domain.com as the publisher domain. 
3. Publisher verification - says company name and has blue tick - requires a partner id on the App registration page in AAD. 

[More info on publisher domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain).

[More info on publisher verification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/publisher-verification-overview)/

Comment: B2C supports Microsoft Accounts, but it requires you to make an AAD multi-tenant app registration in parent tenant. 

On AAD App Registration page is this message: _Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified publishers. I'm not after a blue tick so that's fine. 

The publisher domain, is a verified domain of the AAD Tenant. But when singingin in with a Microsoft account, it says "unverified". So, I tried the .well-known method linked above. But it still says the same thing.

Comment: I just want domain verification for my Multitenant AAD App so that I can use Microsoft 
Accounts for my Azure AD B2C service. 

I think there is either a gap in the product design or the documentation. Or i'm missing something

Comment: Here is a link showing the Consent Prompt:  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience#building-blocks-of-the-consent-prompt)